# How to fetch xml through request body and parse to Spring boot

Tags: java, xml, spring, postman

I am trying to fetch xml through postman into spring boot rest api. But having a problem while fetching the data from it. How to parse it into spring boot application and get the attributes values. Otherwise, How to fetch xml data by creating pojo class.

Following is the xml file:

```
<Transmission>
    <TransmissionHeader/>
    <TransmissionBody>
        <GLogXMLElement>
            <TransmissionReport>
                <Name>FUEL</Name>
                <Number>57</Number>
                <Status>PROCESSED</Status>
                <TransmissionSummary>
                    <FirstTransactionNo>1017</FirstTransactionNo>
                    <LastTransactionNo>1017</LastTransactionNo>
                </TransmissionSummary>
            </TransmissionReport>
        </GLogXMLElement>
    </TransmissionBody>
</Transmission>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"But having a problem while fetching the data from it*"... What kind of problem ? Please provide more information.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring boot, to get the request body -

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
void testEndPoint(@PathVariable String param, @RequestBody String xml) {
//do stuff
}
```

See below for details -

[Spring Boot Guide](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/)

[@RequestBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html)

In order to convert it to POJO, you could explore using Xstream - 
[XStream Tutorial](http://x-stream.github.io/alias-tutorial.html)

Define your POJOs and you can simply do -

```
POJO pojo = (POJO)xstream.fromXML(xml);
```